# Formula to get the Nth substring between a seperator

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have this Image Path on Cell A1:
E:\Test\Coll\01\Red\Example\Untitled-1.jpg
[image: BEFORE]

I want cells B2 to whatever it takes (in my case H2) to show the Nth substring between the separator "\", meaning:
[image: AFTER]

I know the Data to Columns does the exact same thing, but i need it to be dynamic.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula for `B2`

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"\",REPT(" ",100)),(B$1-1)*100+1,100))
```

Copy accross as far as needed